# If I have an integer version of the address in memory of a particular block, how do I make a pointer to this?

Tags: c

I have a previous function which returns the address of a particular block of memory(type int). I now want to memcpy a specific number of bytes of this block to another pointer. How do I access this memory(given that I have the int version of its address) so I can make a proper call to memcpy? I tried casting it as a void* but this did not work.

Comment: You should use `intptr_t` from `stdint.h` rather than `int` - on most 64-bit platforms your pointers will lose bits in the conversion, and quite likely become invalidated.

Comment: @ChrisLutz Bah 64-bit. 4,194,304K of memory should be enough for anybody.

Answer (score 3):

"Casting it as `void*`" is the correct way to do it.

If you have a function with this signature:

```
int getmemaddr();
```

And it returns a memory address, you need to do this:

```
char mybuf[mybuflen];
memcpy(mybuf, (void*)getmemaddr(), mybuflen);
```

... or the like.

Note that an `int` is 32 bits, and so on a 64-bit system it **cannot** represent an arbitrary memory address.

Comment: `int` is at least 16 bits, and can be as many bits as the implementation likes. However, on most common 64-bit architectures, as well as nearly all 32-bit ones, it is 32-bit, which is likely to cause code breakage when porting code from 32 to 64 bits.